# Redirection Error Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a issue still with my_controller.php when I set my config item to true for system_maintenance it redirects to URL page OK, but shows Firefox redirection error **The page isn't redirecting properly** can not seem to load the actual page. the routes are set correctly. I am also trying to remove the word maintenance from URL and only show main URL but still redirect to maintenance URL when set true.

If config_item('system_maintenance') is set to FALSE can see page fine but should work on TRUE rather than false

**Maintenance.php Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Maintenance extends Catalog_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
   }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('admin/users_model');        
        if($this->users_model->isLogged()) {
            return $this->info();
        }
    }

   public function info() {
    $this->lang->load('catalog/maintenance', 'english');
      $data['title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');   
      $data['heading_title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');           
      $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
      $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->lang->line('text_maintenance'),
        'href' => site_url('catalog/common/maintenance')
      ); 
    $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/maintenance', $data);
   }

}
```

**Config.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Checks If System Is Installed
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be set to FALSE on the main application directory if
| you have not set up via the install wizard. You must use install wizard to set up.
| You will not be able to view website if main application system_installed is set to FALSE MY_Controller System Check.
|
*/
$config['system_installed'] = TRUE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Checks If System Is Maintenance Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This system check makes sure user gets redirected to maintenane
| page. If set to true and allow access if set false.
| 
|
*/
$config['system_maintenance'] = TRUE;
```

**My Controller**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
   }
}


class Catalog_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      if(config_item('maintenance')) redirect('maintenance');
   }
}

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      if(!config_item('system_installed')) redirect('install');
   }
}
```

Comment: show your config file

Comment: @saurabh2836 I have edited above its not redirecting properly I am getting the redirection Firefox error

Comment: if (!config_item('system_installed')) redirect('install'); where is this variable set

Comment: install is a separate URL out of the application folder in its on sub folder. That gets user has to remove folder once installed. it also has own true or false in config.php

Comment: use this path in your my controller catalog/controllers/common/maintenance.php replace with maintenance.php

Comment: but I have it set in route $route['maintenance'] = "catalog/common/maintenance/index"; still tried it both ways and still got firefox redirection error. I think it something to do with $his->route trying to remove the word maintenance from url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54834/discussion-between-saurabh2836-and-acoderslife).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my own answer seem to work when have no spaces all working now.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      if(!config_item('system_installed')) redirect('install');
   }
}

class CatalogController extends MY_Controller {
   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      if($this->config->item('system_maintenance') == TRUE) {
         redirect('maintenance');
      }
   }
}
```